# How to escape parameter in windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, escaping

I need to run the following command from the command line in Windows 7:

`SumatraPDF.exe -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files\eclipse\inverse_search.bat\" \"%f\" %l"`

However I need to modify it a little, since my installation of Eclipse is located in here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse (C++)`

How do I escape this line correctly? Do I need to escape parenthesis and pluses too? Or is it just enough to escape double quotes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SumatraPDF.exe -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse (C++)\inverse_search.bat\" \"%f\" %l"
```

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, escape everything.  I find that I don't need to escape (), %, or +, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't even think you need to escape the quotes; it should be enough to do:

```
SumatraPDF.exe -inverse-search ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse (C++)\inverse_search.bat" %f %l"
```