# How to join two text files, removing duplicates, in Windows

Tags: batch-file

file 1

```
A
B
C
```

file 2

```
B
C
D
```

file1 + file2 =

```
A
B
C
D
```

Is it possible to do using cmd.exe?

Comment: Both input files are sorted? Do you want the output in same order?

Comment: It's not simple, but doing it in any programming language would be. Why not use PowerShell or something else?

Answer (score 9):

If you can affort to use a case insensitive comparison, and if you know that none of the lines are longer than 511 bytes (127 for XP), then you can use the following:

```
@echo off
copy file1.txt merge.txt >nul
findstr /lvxig:file1.txt file2.txt >>merge.txt
type merge.txt
```

For an explanation of the restrictions, see [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053).

Comment: +1, but the unique lines of file2.txt will appear after file1.txt. This is not the original order nor sorted order...

Comment: @Aacini - What is the "original order" of the merged data? The merged data never existed before in any order, so how can it have an original order?

Comment: I mean, your method with the files in `file2 file1` order will produce: `B C D A`, that is, just the order of the first file is preserved...

Comment: @Aacini - Actually, it produces 'A B C D' because it first copies file1 in its entirety, then appends new records from file2. But I am uncomfortable stating that this, or any other order, is the "original" order.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't expressed myself correctly. My first solution produce a result in the same order of both sorted input files. All other solutions produce a sorted result because `sort` is required in order for the method to work. The `findstr` method does _not_ produce a sorted result.

Answer (score 8):

Using PowerShell:

```
Get-Content file?.txt | Sort-Object | Get-Unique > result.txt
```

---

For `cmd.exe`:

```
@echo off
type nul > temp.txt
type nul > result.txt,
copy file1.txt+file2.txt temp.txt
for /f "delims=" %%I in (temp.txt) do findstr /X /C:"%%I" result.txt >NUL ||(echo;%%I)>>result.txt
del temp.txt
```

Comment: Or even a bit shorter (for PowerShell): `Get-Content file?.txt | Sort-Object -Unique > result.txt`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY When I use this powershell command it removes the most duplicate occurrence but the size of files almost doubles(input file 14KB > output file 27KB) which mustn't happen at all. Any way we can force prevent the size block ambiguity ?

Answer (score 4):

First part (merging two text files) is possible. (See [Documentation of `copy` command](http://www.computerhope.com/copyhlp.htm))

```
copy file1.txt+file2.txt file1and2.txt
```

For part 2, you can use `sort` and `uniq` utilities from [CoreUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm). This are windows port of the linux utilities.

```
sort file1and2.txt filesorted.txt
uniq filesorted.txt fileunique.txt
```

This has a limitation that you will lose track of original sequencing.

**Update 1**

Windows also ships with a native [SORT.EXE](http://www.computerhope.com/sorthlp.htm).

**Update 2**

Here is [a very simple UNIQ in CMD script](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/PIyQv5Lveq4/discussion)

Comment: Question does not state it is unsorted files. The examples included imply files are sorted. Anyway, adding a qualifier

Comment: file1and2.txt will have `A B C B C D`. That is the output of step 1. Read my answer again. `file1and2.txt` is just concatination of two files in cmd.exe.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40649/discussion-between-erbureth-and-eternal-learner)

Comment: Summary: even if `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` are sorted, their contatenation (`file1and2.txt`) is not, therefore `uniq` cannot be performed before `sort`-ing that file.

Comment: There is not such `cp` command! The Windows command to copy is `copy`.

Comment: Note that Windows SORT is ***not*** case sensitive. So it may not give the correct result if case is important.

Answer (score 3):

You may also use the same approach of Unix or PowerShell with pure Batch, developing a simple `uniq.bat` *filter* program:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "prevLine="
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "^"') do (
   if "%%a" neq "!prevLine!" (
      echo %%a
      set "prevLine=%%a"
   )
)
```

**EDIT**: The program below is a Batch-JScript hybrid version of `uniq` program, more reliable and faster; copy this program in a file called `uniq.bat`:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" & goto :EOF

@end

var line, prevLine = "";
while ( ! WScript.Stdin.AtEndOfStream ) {
   line = WScript.Stdin.ReadLine();
   if ( line != prevLine ) {
      WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(line);
      prevLine = line;
   }
}
```

This way, you may use this solution:

```
(type file1.txt & type file2.txt) | sort | uniq > result.txt
```

However, in this case the result lost the original order.

Comment: How about eliminating intermediate file using `(type file1.txt & type file2.txt)|sort|uniq>result.txt`. A JScript or VBS (or hybrid JScript/batch) implementation of uniq would perform better and be more reliable. The tag says batch-file, but the question just speaks of cmd.exe.

Comment: @dbenham: I like it, Dave! I just modified my answer including it :-)

Comment: Windows SORT is ***not*** case sensitive, so this may not give the correct result if case is important.

Comment: Yes, the funny thing is that we elaborate so much so far on this question, but the OP have not answered yet! I added the Batch-JScript version of uniq.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below assume that both input files are sorted in ascending order using the same order of `IF` command's comparison operators and that does not contain empty lines.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "lastLine=ÿ"
for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do set "lastLine=!lastLine!!lastLine!"

< file1.txt (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (file2.txt) do (
      set "line2=%%a"
      if not defined line1 set /P line1=
      if "!line1!" lss "!line2!" call :advanceLine1
      if "!line1!" equ "!line2!" (
         echo !line1!
         set "line1="
      ) else (
         echo !line2!
      )
   )
)
if "!line1!" neq "%lastLine%" echo !line1!
goto :EOF


:advanceLine1
echo !line1!
set "line1="
set /P line1=
if not defined line1 set "line1=%lastLine%"
if "!line1!" lss "!line2!" goto advanceLine1
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

this joins, sorts and reduce excessive size after PowerShell

```
Get-Content file?.txt | Sort-Object | Get-Unique | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 result.txt
```