# Remove Duplicate Lines from Text File using Windows batching

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to remove duplicated lines from a text file but keeping only 1st occurence using windows batch scripting.

I tried many ways but it's long and not efficient.

would you please help ?

Comment: Show your work so far.

Comment: Yeah, this is the sort of thing GnuWin32 or UnixUtils would really help with.  You could just `uniq infile > outfile` (or, actually, I think `sort infile | uniq > outfile` probably).  This'll be a bit of a pain and inefficient with pure batch -- although it certainly is possible.

Comment: I've tried uniq but it's not supported .. Do you know a way to make it available ?

Comment: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Batch file below do what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "prevLine="
for /F "delims=" %%a in (theFile.txt) do (
   if "%%a" neq "!prevLine!" (
      echo %%a
      set "prevLine=%%a"
   )
)
```

If you need a more efficient method, try this Batch-JScript hybrid script that is developed as a *filter*, that is, similar to Unix `uniq` program. Save it with .bat extension, like `uniq.bat`:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" & goto :EOF

@end

var line, prevLine = "";
while ( ! WScript.Stdin.AtEndOfStream ) {
   line = WScript.Stdin.ReadLine();
   if ( line != prevLine ) {
      WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(line);
      prevLine = line;
   }
}
```

Both programs were copied from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816914/how-to-join-two-text-files-removing-duplicates-in-windows/19818934#19818934).

Comment: This doesn't work if the file contains exclamation marks. :(

Comment: @zreptil: I suppose that with "This" you are referring to the pure Batch version...

Comment: @Aacini Yes, i wanted to edit my comment, but i recognized this ten minutes too late ^^ It only is a problem with the pure batch version. The other version works without any problem :)