# Batch to determine are there duplicate lines in two text files

Tags: batch-file

I need a simple .bat file to determine are there duplicate lines in my 2 text files. I don't need the dupes deleted or even displayed, I only need to know do they exist or not.

Files look like this:

name@gmail.com

blahblah@yahoo.com

iwjeuiwedjdjui@co.uk

john@aol.com

...

Thanks in advance for simple help instead of flaming and trying to make me look stupid.

Answer (score 1):

```
findstr /x /g:"filename1" "filename2"
```

Will find the lines that exist in both files **if they exactly match** and display them.

```
findstr /x /g:"filename1" "filename2">nul
if not errorlevel 1 echo found some
```

will display `found some` if at least one line matches. The `>nul` suppresses output from the `findstr`

Comment: You should add the `/L` option to force a literal search, else the dot will likely trigger a regex search. You should also add the `/I` flag, as most email systems ignore case. `/I` also prevents [this FINDSTR bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053) from being an issue.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, execute this command

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

On Windows, actually not sure because I don't have a windows machine but try one of the following:

[Windows PowerShell to find duplicate lines in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43808886/windows-powershell-to-find-duplicate-lines-in-a-file)

[Remove Duplicate Lines from Text File using Windows batching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241370/remove-duplicate-lines-from-text-file-using-windows-batching)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use: `nin f1.txt f2.txt -m` to get file/pipe intersection. see following screenshot. Use `-A` to hide summary info of `nin.exe`.

`nin.exe` is a single portable exe (about 1.3MB) to get **intersection set** or **difference set** between `2 files` or `a file and a pipe` by `lines` or `keys`. See `nin.exe` in my open project https://github.com/qualiu/msr `tools` directory or built-in doc like: https://qualiu.github.io/msr/usage-by-running/nin-Windows.html

[image: Get files intersection set]