# PHP rawencode & escapeshellarg random " need removing

Tags: php

OK, so:

```
1
    $pool = rawurlencode($_GET['pool']);
    $user = rawurlencode($_GET['user']);
    $pass = rawurlencode($_GET['pass']);
    $url = "?pool=$pool&user=$user&pass=$pass";
    file_get_contents($url);


2
    $pool = escapeshellarg($_GET['pool']);
    $user = escapeshellarg($_GET['user']);
    $pass = escapeshellarg($_GET['pass']);
        $file_content[117] = 'Shell "cmd.exe /c cd %appdata% & test.exe -o ' . $pool. ' -u ' . $user . ' -p ' . $pass . ' -I 13 & pause", vbMaximizedFocus
```

When entering  `teste.net:22555&user=1&pass=1` As a get request I'm getting extra quotes in my code, e.g. in where $pool should be, it's parsing correctly but in quotes like "", same with $user & $pass.

e.g.:

```
Shell "cmd.exe /c cd %appdata% & test.exe -o "test:22555" -u "1" -p "1" -I 13 & pause", vbMaximizedFocus
```

This can't happen I can't have quotes here, please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Shell` is also some shell command, escape the whole argument again:

```
'Shell '.escapeshellarg('cmd.exe /c cd %appdata% & test.exe -o ' . $pool. ' -u ' . $user . ' -p ' . $pass . ' -I 13 & pause').', vbMaximizedFocus'
```

Comment: Hi, yes very good answer thanks so much, however the % for appdata isn't coming through: Shell "cmd.exe /c cd  appdata  & minerd.exe -o  stratum+tcp://test:22555  -u  .1  -p  1   & pause", vbMaximizedFocus      As well as all of these annoying spaces :/

Comment: @user3152114 Just read that `escapeshellarg` replaces `%` with a space to avoid variable expansion. Try either escaping the inner `"` with `^"` or wrap the whole argument in two double-quotes, i. e., `""…""`. Windows is weird.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that mate, I did try ' . $app . ' also, same thing though.

Comment: @user3152114 No, I meant either `'Shell "'.str_replace('"', '^"', 'cmd.exe /c cd %appdata% & test.exe -o ' . $pool. ' -u ' . $user . ' -p ' . $pass . ' -I 13 & pause').'", vbMaximizedFocus'` or `'Shell ""cmd.exe /c cd %appdata% & test.exe -o ' . $pool. ' -u ' . $user . ' -p ' . $pass . ' -I 13 & pause"", vbMaximizedFocus'`.

Comment: This is now happening: Shell "cmd.exe /c cd %appdata% & test.exe -o ^"stratum+tcp://test:22555^" -u ^"1^" -p ^"1^" -I 13 & pause", vbMaximizedFocus

Comment: No, because I'm getting ^" in places i don't want it to be, e.g. pool, user, pass.

Comment: @user3152114 Have a look at [CMD: escape double quotes in parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15262019/53114), maybe that’ll help.