# passing double quotes in commandline argument in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line, command-line-arguments

How do I pass a string with a double quote as a character as a command line argument?

The string basically has a space in between because of which it was getting treated as two different arguments. So I tried putting them in double quotes, like this.

```
wstring cmdLineParam = L"\"Test Value=abc\"";
```

This works perfectly fine in most of the cases. 
But now if I have a double quotes as a character in the string, it fails.

```
wstring cmdLineParam = L"\"Test Value=abc \"test me\"\"";// I want the string to be passed as Value=abc"test me"
```

Here the argument gets split into two arguments

argv[0] =  "Test Value=abc test"
argv[1] = "me"

This is my sample code.

```
wstring cmdLineParam = L"\"Test Value=abc \"test me\"\""; // Need to pass it as Value = abc "xyz uvw"

    wstring path = L"C:\\cmdtest.exe";

    BOOL bSuccess = CreateProcess ((LPCWSTR)path.c_str(), (LPWSTR)cmdLineParam.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                                    NULL, NULL, &si, &piProcess);
```

and as I mentioned, the output is

```
argv[0] =  "Test Value=abc test"
argv[1] = "me"
```

Kindly guide

Thanks & Regards
Sunil

Comment: Have you tried escaping the backslash like this `L"\\\"Test Value=abc \\\"test me\\\"\""`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It didnt work

Comment: There's also the question of whether Windows even supports escaping double quotes in command lines in the first place. (Although, this suggests it should: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx) It's probably better to pass complicated input through stdin.

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760545/cmd-escape-double-quotes-in-parameter and tell us if using the suggested `^` as escape character works.