# How to Specify ^ " white-space At the Same Time in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: regex, windows, diff, gnuwin32, cmdline-args

I have difficulties understanding how to specify special characters `^` and `"` as parameters in windows command prompt.
I am using gnuwin32's `diff` in Win 7 . It has a `-I` option that accepts a regular expression from the command line. I want to invoke `diff` in a batch file specifying a regular expression. However, my regular expression is a complex one with `^ "` and white-space special characters within it:

```
^[ \t]*#[ \t]*include[ \t]+"c:\\program files
```

I'm not able to understand Windows's rules for specifying special characters in the command line in this case which has special rules regarding `^` and `"`. How am i going to specify the above regular expression in the command line?

I guess it should look like this:

```
diff -I "^[ \t]*#[ \t]*include[ \t]+"c:\\program files" file1 file2
```

But the `"` in the middle mess up  the whole thing. How should I deal with the `^` and `"`?

Comment: `echo ^^[ \t]*#[ \t]*include[ \t]+"c:\\program files` would match your string, or try passing it as is but in quotes.

Comment: no, I need to give diff.exe the above string as argument i.e.in the command line: diff -I ^[ ..."... file1 file2. This will fail if I just type it in the command prompt as it contains ^ " and white-space which requires special sequences that I am not able to understand how to specify in windows (the rules are all too complex and inconsistent for me to understand)

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760545/escape-double-quotes-in-parameter>

Comment: Or <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760545/escape-double-quotes-in-parameter>

Answer (score 0):

After some research and testing, this should be the regex required:

```
diff -I "^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*include[[:space:]]\+\"c:\\\\program file" file1 file2
```

For one thing, `diff` is using `grep` style regex which doesn't support the Perl style `\t` sequence. We need to use `\"` to specify  a literal `"`.

Also, do not use windows batch file to test the parameter passed to a program as I did.

In other words, never think this batch file `diff.bat` with a few `echo`s can help you test which command line arguments to use:

```
echo %1
echo %2
echo %3
echo %4
```

Write and compile a program for this and have it dump the command line arguments.

Comment: Note that since it is the application that parses the command line into tokens (or not, as the case may be) there is no guarantee that application A will produce the same tokens as application B.  In this case, gnuwin32 probably uses the Microsoft C runtime parser (although this was probably not the best choice!) so writing your own C program is the appropriate option.  In other cases, you may need to use guesswork, or consult the source code or vendor documentation.

Comment: Oh, one further complication: the caret is cmd.exe's quote character, but like all special characters it only applies outside of double-quote marks.  So the caret in the string you've shown is taken literally because it is between the first two double-quote marks.  If you had to put a caret after the second double-quote mark, you'd need to double it up.