# Process command line argument on windows

Tags: c

I need a hand in terms of processing command line argument (on Windows) in C.

Suppose I have the following situation

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop> my_executable arg1 ' "A>200 && B<300 (just some conditions" '
```

In this case argc = 5

and

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop> my_executable arg1 '"A>200 && B<300 (just some conditions"'
```

In this case argc = 3

Depending on users, the argv and argc will be different.
How can I write the code such that the condition and arg1 can be stored correctly :)
Required:
arg1 is stored into a char pointer
condition is also stored into a char pointer

Thanks

Comment: both have argcount 3, as args are determined by space

Comment: But on my PC the first one has 5

Comment: @self it's determined by space and `"`

Comment: On Windows, it argc will be 5,  argv[] =  `{"my_executable", "arg1", "'", "A>200 && B<300 (just some conditions", "'"}`  Not sure about other platforms.

Comment: [Escape double quotes in parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15262019/995714), [Escaping Double Quotes in Batch Script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31413730/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use single quotes as argument quotes on Windows unless you want to implement your own argument parser. `^` can be used to escape `"` and itself and a few other things. To embed `"` in arguments use `""`.

If you really need to, call `GetCommandLineW` and parse yourself. `GetCommandLineW` returns a string that consists of the executable image name possibly enclosed in double quotes, followed by an optional space and the arguments exactly as given to CreateProcess (which means that `^` processing has already taken place).

Comment: So on window how should the " " type argument be passed? Should they simply be " something "???   What about on Mac???  Thank you :)

Comment: what do you mean by `how should the " " type argument be passed?`? It's not easy to escape `"` in every cases in Windows

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Oh I mean.   How should we pass " condition " to command line?  If we don't use single quotes like in my case. Is it simply my_executable arg1 "conditions" ???