# Issue with create the subject certificate name

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, cer

I want to create subject certificate name which contains "," like the image
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Scm.png)

but always fails because "," is used to separated the contain of -n parameter like
“CA=CARoot,O=My Organization,OU=Dev,C=Denmark”

Anyone know how to add "," into certificate name? Much appreciate for your helping

Comment: How are you creating your certificate in the first place?

Comment: I used this command to create cert: MakeCert.exe -r -pe -n "OU=(c) 2006 thawte Inc. - For authorized use only" -sv "c:\PlaneteersLtd_certificate\XIAMEN_IPRT_TECHNOLOGYLtd1.pvk" -len 2048  "c:\PlaneteersLtd_certificate\XIAMEN_IPRT_TECHNOLOGYLtd1.cer" but can not add "," into OU="..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Windows Command Prompt you can use a triple-double-quote to make a literal double quote in a quoted argument (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15262019/6535399).

The X500 name parser uses commas as separators unless it's in a quoted string.  So you need the -n value to be *interpreted* as `OU="Hey, there", ...`.

So, you can do something like

```
> makecert.exe (etc) -n "OU="""Hey, there""", O=Hmm, CN="""Hello, Nurse!""""
```

or, to make the what-looks-like-a-quadruple-quote go away:

```
> makecert.exe (etc) -n "OU="""Hey, there""", O=Hmm, CN="""Hello, Nurse!""", C=US"
```

Comment: I tried your solution but It did not work, my command: MakeCert.exe -r -pe -n "OU=(c) 2006 thawte Inc."""Hey, there""" - For authorized use only" -sv "c:\PlaneteersLtd_certificate\XIAMEN_IPRT_TECHNOLOGYLtd1.pvk" -len 2048  "c:\PlaneteersLtd_certificate\XIAMEN_IPRT_TECHNOLOGYLtd1.cer" . When I remove """Hey, there""", it create the cert file successfully

Comment: The double quote needs to go immediately after the =, and be terminated before the separator-comma.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your solution but It did not work, my command:

MakeCert.exe -r -pe -n "OU=(c) 2006 thawte Inc."""Hey, there""" - For authorized use only" -sv "c:\PlaneteersLtd_certificate\XIAMEN_IPRT_TECHNOLOGYLtd1.pvk‌​" -len 2048 "c:\PlaneteersLtd_certificate\XIAMEN_IPRT_TECHNOLOGYLtd1.cer‌​"

When I remove """Hey, there""", it create the cert file successfully
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqbJo.png)