# How to Use Git Diff for HTML with Spaces?

Tags: html, git, github, command-line

I have a simple question:

How  can I run the command git diff on my html file when the file name has spaces in it? The name of the file is: Test Business-Tech.html However everytime I run the following command:

git diff Test Business-Tech.html

I get the following error:
**fatal: ambiguous argument 'TEST': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git  [...] -- [...]'
ch.html: command not found**

I cannot change the name of the HTML file... please help!

Comment: Put the name in quotes

Comment: This didn't work either

Comment: Show what you did?

Comment: git diff 'Test Business-Tech.html'

Comment: quotes = ", not '

Comment: If you are on Windows, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15262019/1256452

Answer (score 1):

The answer may depend on the OS you are running, but the first thing I would try is putting a quote around the filename:
git diff 'Test Business-Tech.html'

Comment: This did not work sadly.. I get the following error-->fatal: ambiguous argument 'Test Business-Tech.html': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: UPDATE: Have to use double quotes "Test Business-Tech.html" for it to work :)