# Double quotes not escaping from string when calling Powershell command from within Batch script?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

Double quotes structure is not retained in my test message when passed through a powershell instance called through a batch script, as detailed below:

```
set test={"this":"is","a":"test"}
FOR /F "delims=" %%i in (' powershell -Command "& {$message = '%test%'; echo $message}" ') DO SET message=%%i
echo %test%
echo %message%
```

the output is as follows:

```
{"this":"is","a":"test"}
{this:is,a:test}
```

I would like to retain the quotes to further process the string in powershell, but as you can see, they are stripped when introduced into the `$message` variable.

Any insight as to how I might fix this?

Comment: To escape double quotes in a batch command, you need to use *double* double quotes: `set test={""this"":"is"",""a"":""test""}`, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15262019/1701026

Comment: @iRon
Sadly I attempted this already with these results:

    `{""this"":""is"",""a"":""test""}


    {"this:is,a:test}`

The latter being the output from powershell. Only the first doublequote escapes, but not anything else.

Comment: @iRon: It is PowerShell that is called from the batch file, so you must satisfy _PowerShell's_ escaping requirements re embedded double quotes - and that means escaping them as `\"` when calling the CLI (perhaps surprisingly, given that PowerShell-_internally_ it is `\`"` or `""`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Echoing `%test%` containing double quotes inside the d-quoted powershell command will break the enclosing d-quotes.

One way to overcome this, is using batch string substitution to escape the inner d-quotes with a backslash on the fly

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\04\25\SO_55855412.cmd
@Echo off
set "test={"this":"is","a":"test"}"
FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ('
     powershell -Command "& {$message = '%test:"=\"%'; echo $message}" 
') DO SET "message=%%i"
echo %test%
echo %message%
```

returns here:

```
> SO_55855412.cmd
{"this":"is","a":"test"}
{"this":"is","a":"test"}
```

Another solution is to **NOT** pass `%test%` as an argument, but to get the variable from the inherited environment

```
    powershell -Command "& {$message = $env:test; echo $message}"
```

Sadly this doesn't work to pass a variable back, as on terminating the spawned app the inherited environment is discarded.