# When run node file arguments cut off double quotes

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, cmd

I created node app that should be run through terminal with some parameters like:

```
node index.js --param1="test" --body=<div style="font-family: Lato;">
```

Problem is that when I run this in args I have:

```
[ '--param1=test',
  '--body=<div style=font-family:',
  'Lato' ]
```

I need to pass HTML content inside through parameter but quotes are always stripped off.
Is there any way to get it without putting `\"` before every quote?

```
(function(args){
    console.log(process.argv.slice(2));
}(process.argv.slice(2)))
```

Comment: _“Problem is that when I run this in args I have:”_ - yeah, not really though, right? `Lato` probably did not magically turn into `Arial`, and I’d rather expect the value of the body parameter to be just `<div` (because there is no reason why it should consider this value “ended” only after the second space character, and not the first already.) _“Is there any way to get it without putting \" before every quote?”_ - don‘t know if you can use single quotes as attribute delimiters in this environment, but you could use them for your HTML attributes.

Comment: Arial was a typo sorry. I just realise that even `--body="<div style=\"font-family: Lato;\">` is not solution. I convert this node to exe file and execute from sql server. But can't figure why it stripe quotes always.

Comment: thats generally upto your shell on how it parses the string.

Comment: This exe is executed in windows env from ms sql

Comment: how are you invoking it from mssql exactly?

Comment: For Windows command line, you might need to involve `^` for escaping, or double the quotes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55939478/1427878

Comment: `SET @qry = 'C:\PROGRA~1\SyncData\index.exe ' + @args + ''; EXEC master..xp_CMDShell @qry;`
It produces a string like: `C:\P...\index.exe --body="<div style=\"font-family: Lato;\">"`

Comment: alright i would try what @CBroe suggested as this calls a member `ShellExecute` function.

Comment: I just tried `--body="<div style=\^"font-family: Lato;\^">"` this gives me `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: just a suggestion - why not write the html to a file on disk and have your node utility read it and write it back to a file?

Comment: Impossible as everything must be dynamically generated :( we used sp_SendMail from sql server to send mails but now we need to make outside of sql in a form of exe to pass HTML to it and send email.

Comment: but can you dynamically create the file? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#e-capturing-the-result-of-a-command-to-a-file (i.e. do this but the opposite)

Comment: No can’t save file content anywhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209925/discussion-between-daniel-a-white-and-1110).

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quotes in the parameter value:

`node index.js --param1="test" --body="<div style=""font-family: Lato;"">"`

```
process.argv.slice(2).forEach(param => {
    let equalPos = param.indexOf("=");

    if (equalPos > 0) {
        let name = param.substr(0, equalPos).replace(/^-+/, "");
        let value = param.substr(equalPos + 1);
        console.log(`Arg: ${name} = ${value}`);
    }
});
```

Result:

```
Arg: param1 = test
Arg: body = <div style="font-family: Lato;">
```