# Accessing an domain with curl using the http protocol

Tags: html, linux, curl

Using a CLI debug interface, I can curl a domain from the interface perfectly e.g

```
curl -vLI <domain>
```

but if I prepend http:// to the domain, it outputs nothing. It's not https either, so what is the error in the command?

Comment: best guess: your terminal gets confused by `:` or `//`, in which case the solution is to quote the url, like `curl -vLI '<domain>'`  - but different terminals have different quoting rules, check your terminal's manual for specifics.. like linux's bash use `'` for quoting, and Microsoft Windows's cmd use different quoting rules.. maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760545  if you're using Windows

Comment: @hanshenrik this worked, thanks! It was a unix terminal if i remember correctly so i think it was tripping on the forward slashes.