# How to escape the special characters in a password when using in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping, special-characters

I have this password, `;d#se#&4~75EY(H[SM"%cznGB`.

I need to use this inside an automatically created command line command.

*(using it for TFS Release pipeline, to create a virtual directory and this password belongs to a service user and saved in a global variable as secret input, and TFS puts that password string in doublequotes when creating the command).*

Having a hard time escaping the scpecial characters in it.

What I tried so far is to escape all alphanumeric characters by `^` and escaping `%` and `"` characters by doubling them. But so far, didn't have much luck :(

The list of failed attempts are these.

`;d#se#&4~75EY^(H[SM""%%cznGB`

`;d#se#&4~75EY(H[SM\"%%cznGB`

`^;d^#se^#^&4^~75EY^(H^[SM""%%cznGB`

`^;d^#se^#^&4^~75EY^(H^[SM\"^%cznGB`

`^;d^#se^#^&4^~75EY^(H^[SM\"%%cznGB`

`^;d^#se^#^&4^~75EY^(H^[SM""^%%cznGB`

`;d#se#&4~75EY(H[SM"^^^%%cznGB`

`;d#se#&4~75EY(H[SM"^^^^%%cznGB`

`;d#se#&4~75EY(H[SM^""^%%cznGB`

`^;d^#se^#^&4^~75EY^(H^[SM^""^%%cznGB`

`^;d^#se^#^&4^~75EY^(H^[SM^""%%cznGB`

`;d#se#&4~75EY(H[SM""%%cznGB`

Can you please give me a hand finding the correct escaped string to use it in a batch or in CMD as an inline command?

Before anyone downvotes this question because I posted a password, I edited many parts of it before posting. Just saying :)

UPDATE:

As I mentioned in the question, TFS creates a command text to set the virtual folder access credentials to IIS, for a specific web application. The log shows the command text like this.

`"C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"  set vdir /vdir.name:"appfolder/Files" -physicalPath:"\\servername\virtualfolder" -userName:"sa_user@domain.com" -password:";d#se#&4~75EY(H[SM"%cznGB"`

(I entered the password as it is, for this output)

Comment: Welcome to a world of pain... Maybe you want to use PowerShell instead?

Comment: Yes, it seems that I am welcome :)
But I cannot. I'm stuck with TFS's predefined tasks and they use command line creating their IIS commands. :( It would be easier tough...

Comment: Usually, doublequotes `"` don't need escaping. Percentsigns are escaped by doubling them, other poison chars (only `&` in your example) by a preceding `^`. Of course it all depends, how `tfs` handles the string...

Comment: I forgot to mention. TFS creates the command putting that password input between doublequotes. Updating my question.

Comment: Can you show how this is created in the batch/on cmd? It depends how it is used, then I could help.

Comment: @Gerhard Updated the question to provide the output command text.

Comment: So do you save this command in a batch file, or do you manually run it from cmd?

Comment: If you can `^` escape the quotes around the password, try: `... -password:^";d#se#^&4~75EY(H[SM\^"^%cznGB^"`, otherwise: `... -password:";d#se#&4~75EY(H[SM\"^%cznGB"`. Also worth reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/twistylittlepassagesallalike/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way

Comment: Use `"-password:;d#se#&4~75EY(H[SM""%%cznGB"` (double inner  double quote) or `"-password:;d#se#&4~75EY(H[SM\"%%cznGB"` (escape double quote using a backslash). From a batch file always double percent sign.

Comment: @JosefZ Thank you. But, unfortunately this is the second of my failed trials (see the question). I am afraid I have no clue what to try next :(
Tried that again, to make sure, but the same result...

Comment: Any luck with mine?

Comment: Yes, I know. However, note that I advise other placement of the opening double quote: `"-password:;d#se#&4~75EY(H[SM""%%cznGB"` instead of `-password:";d#se#&4~75EY(H[SM""%%cznGB"`

Comment: @JosefZ yes, I see that, but I have no control over how the command is created. I can only enter a parameter, and the command is created by the system as -password:"blabla" format. nothing I can control...

Comment: @Iridium Sorry, I also tried yours, with no luck...

Comment: @Gerhard I have no control on the created output. I just enter a variable in TFS and it creates a command and runs it on its own.

Comment: I understand, I was trying to see how you initiate this so I could help, but I see that you are ok now. :)

Comment: @Iridium.. I think you might be misunderstand the escaping double quotes part. Escaping of double quotes is not required. you can see the results by doing `echo "string"` and `echo ^"string^"`. There are only certain times where the first set of double quotes are consumed by `cmd` so we have to double up, but actually escaping double quotes that are quoting an item will not solve the issue here.

Comment: @Gerhard - The purpose of `^`-escaping *all* the quotes is to avoid cmd's quote handling entirely. It may not be strictly necessary, but it avoids having to deal with the cmd command-line parsing rules on top of the (subtly different) Windows API command-line parsing rules, the latter being easier to deal with, since it permits escaping double-quotes within double-quoted strings. See the link in my comment for more details on the rationale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How interesting this all character escaping thing works!
I continued serching, and read everything I could find. The result is that all that should be escaped with in double quotes, are the double quotes themselves...

*(correct me if there's something I am missing, that was correct for my case)*

The resulting string that should be used in the TFS variable (and I tested it, it works!) is this:

```
;d#se#&4~75EY(H[SM""%cznGB
```

**The only thing I added to the original password was another double quote near the double quote.**

That answer certainly helped me. No wonder why experementing by yourselves preserves better than reading tons of articles :/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15262019/2443719

Thanks to everyone who commented and left an answer to this thread.

Comment: ok, so in actual fact the first double quotes were consumed by the prompt. That is the reason I asked how this is used, then We could have determined that earlier, but you did good research, so well done.