# openssl PKCS12 export - wrong behaviour while using single quote character in password

Tags: openssl, single-quotes

I am exporting a PKCS12 Keystore using the openssl command: `openssl pkcs12 -export -out /root/pkcs12.pfx`
However it seems, that openssl doesn't support single quotes in the password very well.
If I enter this password for example: `!"§'"§!\/!"77` I am not able to open that keystore, neither with the java keytool, nor with a Windows PC.

I've tried both, the interactive password supply, and also the `-password pass:<my-password>` option with escaped single quotes.

Are there any known problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a openssl problem but with escaping in whatever you are using.  How to escape will depend on what you are running in.
e.g. Windows command prompt, powershell prompt, or linux bash shell are examples.

I would say the best advise is to remove the shell type and use files.
e.g. -passin file:xxx or -passout file:xxx

If your specifically talking about the windows command prompt and the password **!"§'"§!/!"77** in your example I would do:

> -passin "pass:!""§'""§!/!""77"

You can see this sort of double quoting in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15262019/23235).