# MongoDB Export Query to CSV using MongoExport

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I really need help with the following problem with mongoexport :

1. First of all the query is success with the following filter:

   ```
        db.payment_billers.find({
        createdDate : {
            $gte : ISODate("2022-04-01T00:00:00.000+07:00"),
            $lt : ISODate("2022-05-01T00:00:00.000+07:00")
         }
       })
   ```
2. Then I tried to export the result to csv using this line:

   ```
    mongoexport --db=sigmob --collection=payment_billers
    --query='{createdDate : {$gte : ISODate("2022-04-01T00:00:00.000+07:00"),$lt : ISODate("2022-05-01T00:00:00.000+07:00")}}' --type=csv
    --fields=_id,accountSource.account.number,createdDate  --out=D:/download/220430/payment_billers.csv
   ```

Resulting :

```
2022-05-11T14:24:54.092+0700    error parsing command line options: error parsing positional arguments: provide only one MongoDB connection string. Connection strings must begin with mongodb:// or mongodb+srv:// schemes
2022-05-11T14:24:54.093+0700    try 'mongoexport --help' for more information
```

I tried the script without using the query and works great. Really need help to correct the script, and thank you guys for the help and attention.

Comment: Try `mongoexport -d sigmob -c payment_billers` instead of `mongoexport --db=sigmob --collection=payment_billers`

Comment: Try this
mongoexport -d=sigmob -c= payment_billers -q='{$and:[{ "createdDate": { "$gte": { "$date": "2022-04-01T00:00:00.000+07:00" } },{ "createdDate": { "$lt": { "$date": "2022-04-01T00:00:00.000+07:00" } }]}' --out=exportdir/myRecords.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error arises when there is some redundant text in the end of the command (`mongoexport` treats it as *connection string*, hence the message). It may happen because your shell doesn't interpret your command in the way you expect.

What type of shell do you use? It seems you may use Windows `cmd`, which doesn't support single quotes. You should rather use double quotes for `--query` argument and escape double quotes inside the query with `"""` (read more about this escaping rule [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15262019/14967413)):

```
--query="{"""createdDate""" : {"""$gte""" : ISODate("""2022-04-01T00:00:00.000+07:00"""),"""$lt""" : ISODate("""2022-05-01T00:00:00.000+07:00""")}}"
```

Note that I use double quotes also for field name `createdDate` and operators `$gte` and `$lt`, which is mandatory in `mongoexport` (see [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/#std-option-mongoexport.--query)).

In you are using Linux `bash` your command should work properly after just enclosing field name and operators in simple double quotes.

```
--query='{"createdDate" : {"$gte" : ISODate("2022-04-01T00:00:00.000+07:00"),"$lt" : ISODate("2022-05-01T00:00:00.000+07:00")}}'
```