# Arguments in command line shell

Tags: delphi, cmd

I open an .exe file in CMD shell like this:
**d:/program1.exe text1 text2 text3 text4 text5** 
 How can i use text3 text4 text5 as single parameter? Thanks

Comment: They are pass to your program as arguments by cmd,so you have to find out the global variable which used for storing/pointing to programs arguments.

Comment: Just enclose all required parts of a single parameter in quotes, like that: `program.exe "text1 text2 text3 text4 text5" more-optional-params`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use quotes around parameters that contain spaces:

```
d:/program1.exe text1 text2 "text3 text4 text5"
```

When you invoke you program like this ParamStr(1) is 'text1', ParamStr(2) is 'text2' and ParamStr(3) is 'text3 text4 text5'.

Comment: How i should use quotes when text3 text4 text5 having quotes, by example like this: Integer: "20"

Comment: @user1533838 You will have to choose your own rules for escaping the quotes, and then parse the command line yourself. `ParamStr()` has no support for escaping double-quotes. Get the command line by calling `GetCommandLine`.

Comment: @David it looks like escaping is supported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403647

Comment: @jachguate The OS doesn't parse the command line for you. It's done by the RTL. In the case of Delphi, its RTL support is ParamStr. And that doesn't support arguments containing double quotes

Comment: I have several QC reports that are related to `ParamStr()` and `ParamCount()` parsing issues - see [3946](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=3946), [27451](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=27451), and [43340](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=43340). #43340 is specifically about the lack of support for inline quotes.

Comment: @Remy It's pretty lame that they won't fix this. It can't be back-compat that stops them. All they need to do is add a function named `UsePlatformStandardArgumentParsing` to allow us to opt-in to fixed variants of `ParamStr()`