# Matlab compiler with special character string as input

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

So I need to run my program in the windows prompt like this:
my_program somestring.

The problem is that somestring can contain characters like &.
I get problems like:
'si' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
Where 'si' is after & in the string.

I just want to read the whole string.
What can I do?

Edit: It seems to work if I put "" around somestring.
But this is not something I can control.

Comment: No, I dont control the string

Comment: What can you control then?

Comment: My program has to take the input given. The program can be and .exe or .bat. Could I make a script that gets the string and then puts " " around them or something?

Comment: No you would face the same problems, wouldn't you. Whowever gives the parameters to your programm and is calling your programm is responsible for escaping correctly. Just lean back and relax. (Maybe agree to put parameters in a file and then give the file name as parameter.)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to believe that [this error](https://www.google.nl/search?q=is%20not%20recognized%20as%20an%20internal%20or%20external%20command) is returned by matlab, however that is not the case.

This error is returned as a result of the command prompt being unable to run your command. As such we can conclude the following:

1. The string never reaches your matlab program
2. Changing your matlab code will not help in any way

You already seem to know how to solve it from the side of the input as was also decribed in [How to escape parameter in windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403647/how-to-escape-parameter-in-windows-command-line). But unfortunately the answer is that there does not appear to be another way.

**Conclusion**

If you enter an invalid string in the command prompt, there is nothing you can do in matlab to 'make it work'.