# Windows command line parameter escape

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, command-line-arguments

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (string s in args) Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Run the app in command line window:

```
"app.exe" "\\\\" "\'" "\\'"  "\\\'"
```

Result:

```
\\
\'
\\'
\\\'
```

What is the logic behind the 2-4 result - why any ' at tail make all double \ before not escaped to single \ ?

(FYI if there is no ' then there have to be even \ or the second " get escapaed by the left \ )

Expand the question: what is the general way to escape any string then when you put it inside double quotes as a parameter in a command line:

```
... "..." "escaped-string" "..." ...
```

then can guarantee a C# program get that parameter as the original string?

Still puzzled after read this [How to escape parameter in windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403647/how-to-escape-parameter-in-windows-command-line)

Comment: The problem (if it is a problem) appears to exist only when an input argument ends with a series of backslashes and is not followed by a character. In that case they are reduced from a couple of two to one. So for example \\\\share\\temp has the same behavior of cases 2-4.

Comment: @Steve That's nice insight, I didn't notice this.